# Output currency symbols

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, currency

Is there a way to output the currency symbols for each accepted payment currency in a Craft Commerce site?

Consider the following simplified example;

```
{% set currencies = craft.commerce.paymentCurrencies %}
{% if currencies|length > 1 %}
<select name="paymentCurrency">
    {% for currency in currencies %}
        <option>{{ currency.iso }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
{% endif %}
```

Instead of the currency ISO code being output in the option, I also want to show the symbol. I can't find a method for doing so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to create your own symbol map - it exists as a yii translation:

```
{% set localeData = craft.i18n.getLocaleData() %}
{% set currencyIso = 'USD' %}

{{ localeData.getCurrencySymbol(currencyIso)  }}
```

Comment: Wish I'd known this on a previous project! Upvoted!

Comment: @JasonMayo I try to learn Craft by answering questions here. This one was easy: I searched for the '€' symbol in the code base and researched how to access the translation data. I'm glad it was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find a way to do this (So hopefully someone can come back on this, or it will be part of Commerce in future!)

But what I did was to create an array matching the ISO's to the symbol then checked the array if the symbol existed. Luckily we only offered a few currencies so it wasn't so much of a pain.

Comment: Simple mapping arrays are a nice way to customise an output. I usually setup a config/businesslogic.php configuration file to keep things organised. Then in the template (this is good use case for a Twig macro) I can get the data: `{% set map = craft.config.get('currencyMap', 'businesslogic') %}`.

Comment: @carlcs That's a great idea, might do that in future. Always had issues using custom variables etc across templates